# How to find the combination count in scala?

Tags: scala

My dataset contain 5 columns with last column as classindex. I want the combination of each column with that classindex values.

```
"sunny", "hot", "high", "false","no"
"sunny", "hot", "high", "true","no"
"overcast", "hot", "high", "false","yes"
"rainy", "mild", "high", "false","yes"
```

I want the combination sunny & yes = 0, sunny & no = 2, overcast & yes = 1, rainy & yes = 2.

Comment: @AkhilaV, I assume this is course work as others have asked similar questions before. Please search for other answers first -  I found quite a few with http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=overcast+sunny+rainy+%5Bscala%5D

Answer (score 0):

The description of your dataset seems a little bit vague to me but, which data structure are you using to represent it?

Imagine it is a list, you could try something like:

```
l =>  (l.head, l.last)
```

Applying this to the entire set:

```
val dataset = List(
    "sunny"::"hot"::"high"::"no"::Nil,
    "sunny"::"hot"::"high"::"no"::Nil,
    "overcast"::"hot"::"high"::"yes"::Nil,
    "rainy"::"mild"::"high"::"yes"::Nil
)

val qualified = dataset.map(l => (l.head, l.last))
```

Once you have your elements qualified with "yes"/"no" class you can group your occurrences and count the number of element of each group:

```
val countMap = qualified.groupBy(x => x).map(kv => (kv._1, kv._2.size))
```

Or the shorter form:

```
val countMap = qualified.groupBy(x => x).mapValues(_.size)
```

In order to list all possibilities, even though their count is 0, you can generate all possible combinations and use the map to look-up each count value:

```
(
    for(
        st <- dataset.map(_.head).toSet[String];
        q  <- dataset.map(_.last).toSet[String]
       ) yield (st,q)
).map(k => (k, countMap.getOrElse(k,0)))

> Set(((rainy,no),0), ((sunny,yes),0), ((sunny,no),2), ((rainy,yes),1), ((overcast,yes),1), ((overcast,no),0))
```

Comment: I change my dataset. So last column is the classindex column. I want each column distinct values with classindex combination with  count

Comment: the same on an RDD instead of a List ,how we can make the combination

Answer (score 0):

Gather each row into a case class `Weather` with 5 properties,

```
case class Weather(p1: String, p2: String, p3: String, p4: String, p5: String)
```

and so for

```
val xs = Array(
  Weather("sunny", "hot", "high", "false","no"),
  Weather("sunny", "hot", "high", "true","no"),
  Weather("overcast", "hot", "high", "false","yes"),
  Weather("rainy", "mild", "high", "false","yes"))
```

group the entries by the first and last properties, and then count the amount of grouped instances, for instance like like this,

```
xs.groupBy( w => (w.p1,w.p5) ).mapValues(_.size)
```

which delivers

```
Map((overcast,yes) -> 1, (sunny,no) -> 2, (rainy,yes) -> 1)
```

However this approach does not account for `missing` or not declared groups such as `"sunny"` and `"yes"`.